# rename the default ID python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concat two dataFrames but the two data have a different ID so the result is wrong
this is my code

```
data=pd.DataFrame(df.columns)
data1=data.drop(axis=1,index=[0,1,2,3]).transpose()
data1
```

this is the dataframe1
[image]

the other dataframe:

```
y=sma_algo(df.loc['H+L'],5)
sma = pd.DataFrame(y).transpose()
sma
```

the result
[image]

now I want to concat the two dataframe

```
frame=[sma,data1]
concat=pd.concat(frame,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
concat
```

[image]

I want both dataframes begin from column=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
data1.loc[len(data1), :] = y
```

But if want default values of columns:

```
data1.columns = np.arange(len(data1.columns))
```